# Stack Program in C++

Tags: c++, stack

I want to implement a code in my program where it guesses whether or not the given series of operations and corresponding return values from an input file are operating as a stack. In other words, the output is fully determined by the input file.

**The text file (StackTest.txt):**

```
4
INSERT 2
INSERT 1
REMOVE 1
REMOVE 2
6
INSERT 5
INSERT 10
INSERT 12
REMOVE 10
REMOVE 5
REMOVE 12
2
INSERT 8
REMOVE 8
```

**Expected Output(from input file):**

```
stack
not stack
stack
```

However, I'm stuck on how to implement this feature into my current code.

If anyone can help me out on how to achieve the expected output above or give me some hints, I would really appreciate it!

**Code in progress...**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

// Function to check validity of stack sequence
bool validStackSeq(string input, int len)
{
    // maintain count of popped elements
    int j = 0;

    // an empty stack
    stack <int> s;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        s.push(input[i]);

        // check if appended value is next to be popped out
        while (!s.empty() && j < len && s.top() == input[j])
        {
            s.pop();
            j++;
        }
    }

    return j == len;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    string data;

    string command;
    int num;

    inFile.open("StackTest.txt");
    //cout << "Reading file..." << endl;

    stack <int> s;

    while(getline(inFile, data))
    {
        if(command == "INSERT")
        {
            s.push(num);
        }
        else if(command == "REMOVE")
        {
            s.pop();
        }

        num = sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);

        cout << (validStackSeq(data, num) ? "Stack" : "Not Stack") << endl;
    }

    inFile.close();
}
```

**Current Output**

```
Stack
Stack
Stack
Stack
Stack
Stack
Stack
Stack
Stack
Stack
Stack
Stack
Stack
Stack
Stack
```

**Stack Validation Program (without input file)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

bool validStackSeq(int pushed[], int popped[], int len)
{
    int j = 0;

    stack <int> pt;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        pt.push(pushed[i]);

        while (!pt.empty() && j < len && pt.top() == popped[j])
        {
            pt.pop();
            j++;
        }
    }

    return j == len;
}

// Driver code
int main()
{
   int pushed[] = {2, 1};
   int popped[] = {1, 2};
   int len = sizeof(pushed)/sizeof(pushed[0]);

   int pushed1[] = {5, 10, 12};
   int popped1[] = {12, 5, 10};
   int len1 = sizeof(pushed1)/sizeof(pushed1[0]);

   int pushed2[] = {8};
   int popped2[] = {8};
   int len2 = sizeof(pushed2)/sizeof(pushed2[0]);

   int pushed3[] = {1, 4};
   int popped3[] = {4};
   int len3 = sizeof(pushed3)/sizeof(pushed3[0]);

   cout << (validStackSeq(pushed, popped, len) ? "Stack" : "Not Stack") << endl;

   cout << (validStackSeq(pushed1, popped1, len1) ? "Stack" : "Not Stack") << endl;

   cout << (validStackSeq(pushed2, popped2, len2) ? "Stack" : "Not Stack") << endl;

   cout << (validStackSeq(pushed3, popped3, len3) ? "Stack" : "Not Stack") << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use some [standard C++ container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), read a good [C++ programming book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) then the [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) C++ standard. Read [the Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) about usual [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques.

Comment: I updated my code using some code from the stack validation program. I think I'm onto something but of course it's not 100% correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform the INSERT and REMOVE operations as specified in the text file. The result is 'stack' if all remove operations are possible (do not occur when the stack is empty) and the operand of each remove operation equals the actual value poped from your stack.

**UPDATED 2020-02-29**

You cannot create two separate arrays for INSERT and REMOVE operations and process them independently, because the result depends on how the operations are interleaved. For example

```
INSERT 1
INSERT 2
REMOVE 2
REMOVE 1
```

should result in `stack`, but if we move one REMOVE operation up:

```
INSERT 1
REMOVE 2
INSERT 2
REMOVE 1
```

the result will become `not stack`. It means that you need to process the operations in exactly same order as they appear in the file.

The general structure of the code:

```
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open("StackTest.txt");

  int num;
  while (inFile >> num) {  // Read number of INSERT/REMOVE in each test set
    stack<int> s;
    bool isStack = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       // Read and process all INSERT/REMOVE operations in this test set 
       // Set isStack to false if not stack behavior detected
    }
    cout << (isStack ? "stack" : "not stack") << endl;
  }
  inFile.close();
```

As we read the operations from the input file we try to perform them. The INSERT operations should be performed as-is, no checks are required.

```
      if (operation == "INSERT") {
        s.push(argument);
      }
```

The REMOVE operations require two checks to be performed: whether the stack is empty and whether the top of stack contains the same number as the argument of the REMOVE operation. If either of the checks fail then we set isStack to false.

```
      if (operation == "REMOVE") {
        if (s.empty() || s.top() != argument) {
          isStack = false;
        }
        if (!s.empty()) {
          s.pop ();
        }
      }
```

Combining this together we get:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open("StackTest.txt");
  int num;
  while (inFile >> num) {
    stack<int> s;
    bool isStack = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      string operation;
      int argument;
      inFile >> operation >> argument;
      if (!isStack)
        continue;
      if (operation == "INSERT") {
        s.push(argument);
      }
      else if (operation == "REMOVE") {
        if (s.empty() || s.top() != argument) {
          isStack = false;
        }
        if (!s.empty()) {
          s.pop ();
        }
      }
    }
    cout << (isStack ? "stack" : "not stack") << endl;
  }
  inFile.close();
}
```

There is just one more thing to mention: after we read the operation name and its argument from the file we do a check

```
      if (!isStack)
        continue;
```

This statement is not required, it's there just for a performance improvement. If we already detected that the given test set does not correspond to a stack then we don't need to perform all the remaining operations in this test set, we just skip them. You can safely remove this statement without influencing the result.

Comment: Can you provide me an example code? I added my code in progress based on your input so far. I made another program that validates a stack sequence, but it only takes input in the code, not from an input file.